# Question on the Lebesgue-Radon-Nikodym Theorem (Folland, page 90, theorem 3.8)

Tags: measure-theory

I might be missing something simple here because I can't seem to find someone asking/answering this question anywhere..

In the third paragraph of this proof (begins with "We claim that...") Folland gives the definition 
$$d \lambda = d \nu - f d \mu.$$
I don't understand what this definition means? What exactly is $d \lambda$? One page before (page 89) Folland gives the general definition 
$$d \nu = f d \mu$$
$$\implies v(E) = \int_E f d\mu$$
Trying to apply this definition, to the definition I am confused about gives me 
$$d \lambda = d \nu - f d \mu$$
$$ = f d \mu - f d \mu$$
$$ = 0$$
which doesn't make sense. What am I missing here? Can someone help me out by explaining what 
$$d \lambda = d \nu - f d \mu$$
means?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

$d\lambda=d\nu-f\;d\mu$ means
$$ \lambda(E)=\nu(E)-\int_Ef\;d\mu$$

The measure $\nu$ in the theorem is some $\sigma$-finite signed measure. It does not necessarily have any relation to $\mu$.

Comment: What exactly is the difference then between $d\lambda$ and $\lambda$ (if any)? He seems to use them interchangeably in that paragraph.

Comment: $d\lambda=d\nu-f\;d\mu$ is a convenient shorthand for "$\lambda$ is the signed measure defined by $\lambda(E)=\nu(E)-\int_Ef\;d\mu$". So $d\lambda$ and $\lambda$ can be used interchangeably.